# Why does Log4Net sometimes prepends Property. to properties in logs, but sometimes it doesn't?

Tags: c#, log4net

A sample line from my log might look like:

> {"date":"2015-05-20T16:33:52.2825750-05:00","level":"INFO","sitename":"sitenamehere","logger":"loggergoeshere","thread":"6","property.ApplicationName":"AppnameWithPrefix","property.Username":"USER","property.log4net:Identity":"","property.EnvironmentName":"local","property.log4net:UserName":"USER","property.log4net:HostName":"HOST","message":"MassTransit v2.9.2/v2.9.0.0, .NET Framework v4.0.30319.34209","ApplicationName":"AppnameWithoutPrefix","EnvironmentName":"local","UserName":"USER"}

Basically, in the beginning of the line, `ApplicationName` and `EnvironmentName` are prefixed with "property." and I would like to get rid of that. For some of the parts of this application (specifically web based stuff) the prefix doesn't show up. I can't figure out what is doing it.

Conversion pattern

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
      <conversionPattern value="%env{SPOTLITE_LOG_DIR}\%property{ApplicationName}\%property{ApplicationName}_%property{EnvironmentName}_%date{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" />
    </file>
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json">
      <decorator type='log4net.Layout.Decorators.StandardTypesDecorator, log4net.Ext.Json' />
      <default />
      <!--explicit default members-->
      <remove value='message' />
      <!--remove the default preformatted message member-->
      <member value='message:messageobject' />
      <member value='ApplicationName' />
      <member value='EnvironmentName' />
      <member value='UserName' /> 
      <!--add raw message-->
      <!--add raw message-->
    </layout>
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  </appender> 

  <appender name="ColoredConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender,log4net">
    <mapping>
      <level value="FATAL" />
      <foreColor value="White, HighIntensity" />
      <backColor value="Red, HighIntensity" />
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
      <level value="ERROR" />
      <foreColor value="White" />
      <backColor value="Red" />
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
      <level value="WARN" />
      <foreColor value="Yellow" />
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <foreColor value="Green" />
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <foreColor value="White" />
    </mapping>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your config, including the conversion pattern you are using?

Comment: How much would you need? I'll edit in the conversion pattern.

Comment: I tried a sample console and web project using your provided config, and I could not reproduce it. I used the latest version of log4net.Ext.Json. Can you share the code you are using to log?

Comment: I ended up just not using log4net.ext.json. I guess I should close this.

Comment: @BLevyCS Don't close this, it is a correct and valid question